# Interleaving data in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to interleave two streams of data in matlab:

```
upper = rem(conv(data, [1 1 1 1]),2);
lower = rem(conv(data, [1 1 0 1]),2);
t = [upper; lower];
```

How would I go about it?

Comment: what's wrong with that way?

Comment: I just like to do things multiple ways.

Comment: I promise you there are many ways to accomplish that but I doubt  you'll find a faster or more elegant way than this.

Comment: why did you delete the way you originally posted? that is `t(:)'` ?

Comment: Because then I'd not learn anything - I'd just get your question again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

say `a` and `b` are the vectors you want to interleave into a vector `c`. you can try:

```
c=kron(a,[1 0])+kron(b,[0 1]);
```

or:

```
c(numel(a)+numel(b))=0;
c(1:2:end)=a; 
c(2:2:end)=b;
```

For the sake of fairness I'll add the original suggestion of the OP

```
t=[a;b]
c=t(:)'
```